# Ignore line break in Indesign

Tags: javascript, ios, applescript, adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

In my Indesign document having the text "This is Indesign \napplication"----here \n is the line break.

Then, I am find text in grep 
find grep:This is Indesign application

The text cannot be selected. because, the sentence contain line breaks.

So, Please help me to select the sentence.

Thanks & regards by,
Annadurai.

Comment: Please decide which tag is the correct one! Do you mean the GREP-search-dialog inside InDesign or AppleScript or JavaScript (ESTK)? Using the right tags helps us who want to help you...

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea: try searching for whitespace between words. This can be done via regular expressions, either with grep or with javascript.

To do this, you have to search for "This\s+is\s+Indesign\s+application". Each "\s+" means: one or more whitespace characters (blanks, newlines, tabs). Code snippet for javascript:

```
string.search(/This\s+is\s+Indesign\s+application/);
```

If this does not help, you should provide more information of what you've done so far.